# Unity 5.6 build apk for 64bit for Play store

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, google-play, 32bit-64bit

I built an apk (32 bit) in unity 5.6 . But when I upload it in Play store, it says that the app is not compliant to 64 bit requirement. So I decompiled the apk file with an online decompiler, and imported into Android Studio. I have never used Android Studio before. Is it possible to build this apk into 64 bit in Android Studio. Or is there an alternative method?

I am using:
Windows 7 - 32 bit
Unity 5.6

Comment: Unity 5.6. Dude, just update your Unity version...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any external library that requires 64 bits? If not, you still can publish your app. I had the same issue with an Ionic app, but I could publish it anyway...

Comment: Yes. I am using Unity's library. It is an external library I think

Answer (score 0):

Does that version of unity have the Google app bundle option on the build settings? I just released an app and that's how I had to go about it.